# Is there any reason to reference UI element text in the strings.xml resource file rather than hard-coding in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

It seems like it's simply more straightforward to hard-code the text values. In an event that these values should be changed it seems like it would be more logical to search for the relevant UI element in each activity's xml layout file rather than look through the entire strings.xml. Of course if you have certain UI elements across multiple activities that all share the same text then this might be an exception (like a back button for instance), but generally there doesn't seem to be much advantage to storing these in the strings.xml. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, @coder19 if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @RemonShehatta just did! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you two reasons; 
1 - Avoid duplication:  all of your strings in one place. also, you can use string value many times. when you want to change it, there is one place to do the change. that makes it easier to maintain.

2 - Multi-language support: if you want to translate your strings to another language you must have all the strings in Strings.xml

let me know if you need more clarifications.